# StackOverflowError during filtering a Scala stream

Tags: scala

I'm trying to filter a stream with a predicate, but when I try to convert the stream to a list that contains an element that the predicate returns `false` for, I receive an error.

```
def machine(n:Int) = if (n==0) List(0) else List(n/2,n/3,n/4)
def greater(n:Int) = machine(n).sum > n

val d: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: d.map(_+1).filterNot(greater)

scala> d.take(11).toList
res41: List[Int] = List(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

//12 is the first number for which greater will return true
scala> d.take(12).toList
//Returns a ton of scala.collection.immutable.Stream errors
```

Could someone please explain to me what exactly is going wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works recursively.  When you run out of items in your stream, recursion gets you nowhere, and eventually you run out of stack space.  (What are you expecting to happen when you ask for more items than can possibly be in your stream because you filter out all the large ones?  You should either get a stack overflow or non-termination (hang), right?)

Comment: Sure, hanging is the right behavior here, but I wouldn't expect it to consume linear stack during long runs of filtered elements.

Comment: @MyseriousDan - Lazy data structures don't always consume stack the way you'd expect, at least if implemented in the naive way.

Comment: I realize that (I come from Haskell-land) but a stack overflow in a library function being used in a permissible way seems wrong to me. Consuming linear stack is almost never the right thing to do.

Comment: @MyseriousDan - Probably not.  The library implementations could use a lot of work in that regard.  (It is considerably faster to use the stack if you can get away with it, though.)